# Getting 404 on 2Checkout Order Creation

Tags: node.js, 2checkout

I have been struggling to create order on 2checkout using EES_TOKEN (2pay.js)

When I execute the api request at `https://api.2checkout.com/rest/6.0/orders`, I am getting

```
 error_code: 'RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND', message: 'Resource not found' }
```

Before this I am creating customer, and that's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted the support and they gave me this reply (Attaching photo)

[image]

I can feel, how stupid it is :)